# Install Windows 7 over Windows XP - Permissions

Tags: windows-7

i want to install Windows 7 in a workstation where windows xp is currently installed.

The system has 2 hard drives with 5 partitions and there are permissions on folders on different partitions. After the installation of Windows 7 will these permissions be visible?

Will the permissions be lost? Will i have to re-gain control over the folders in these partitions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As you cannot make an in-place upgrade of XP to Windows 7 you will lose the permissions on the folders when you make a fresh installation.

I would not be amazed if there was a program that could capture the permissions.  Then re-apply them from within Windows 7.  But even if it's possible, it may be just as quick to re-create the permissions.

Rest assured, you will see the folders from the second installation.

What about the users is this a Workgroup or Domain situation?

Comment: If it's a workgroup, I don't suppose there are more than a handful of users to re-assign permissions.